# Run-Time Error for 8-Piece Puzzle Game

Tags: java, swing

I admit, this problem pertains only to my code as it is a run-time error that does not give me the results I was hoping for.  I am newer to Java and tried making this game that is meant to swap out a number with the blank piece in order to match them up in the order 1,2,3,4,-,5,6,7,8.  So far, it runs, takes my input for a number, but does not refresh the board.  If I enter the number 1 into the text box, it refreshes the board, but nothing on it changes.  It then proceeds ti ask me for another value.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class EightPuzzle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        char[] grid={'1', '4', '3', '-', '6', '5', '2', '7', '8'};
        char[] goal={'1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '5', '6', '7', '8'};      
        char move='9';
        boolean isGoal=false;
        while(!isGoal){
            //***********GET MOVE START********************
            int choice=-1;
            boolean valid=false;
            while(valid==false){
                choice=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(getGridForOutput(grid) + "\nWhich tile do you wish to move? (1-8)").charAt(0);
                if(choice<=8&&choice>=0&&grid[choice]!='-'){
                    move=(char)(choice);
                    valid=true;
                }
            }
            //***********GET MOVE END***************************

            //***********GET TILE LOCATION START***************************
            int location=-1;
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<9;i++)
                if(move==grid[i])
                    location=i;
            //***********GET TILE LOCATION END***************************

            //*********UPDATE START**************
            char temp='0';
            temp=(char)(location);
            grid[temp]='-';
            //***************GET LOCATION OF BLANK START*****************
            int j=0;
            for(i=0;i<9;i++)
                if(grid[i]=='-')
                    j=i;
            //***************GET LOCATION OF BLANK END*********************
            grid[j]=move;   
            //*********UPDATE END***********
            //****** IS GOAL START**********
            if(grid[0]==goal[0]&&grid[1]==goal[1]&&grid[2]==goal[2]&&grid[3]==goal[3]&&grid[4]==goal[4]&&grid[5]==goal[5]&&grid[6]==goal[6]&&grid[7]==goal[7]&&grid[8]==goal[8])
                isGoal=true;
            //*******IS GOAL END**********
        }
    }
    public static String getGridForOutput(char[] grid)
    {
        return ""+grid[0]+"\t "+grid[1]+"\t "+grid[2]+"\n"+grid[3]+"\t "+grid[4]+"\t "+grid[5]+"\n"+grid[6]+"\t "+grid[7]+"\t "+grid[8];
    }

}
```

Comment: Tipp: You will get more errors, because you use chars as indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you evaluate the integer code of the first char of the users input.
Use the entire input with Integer.valueOf(input) to get the int representation of the user input

```
String choiceText=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(getGridForOutput(grid) + "\nWhich tile do you wish to move? (1-8)");
int choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceText);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct. You are receiving input as a character, but are testing its integer value. You can test this by adding a `System.out.println` to see the value of choice before your `if` statement.

A couple of things you could do is get the integer value by using `Integer.parseInt()`, or manipulate choice directly by writing:
`choice-=48;` or
`choice-='0';`.